# Add Firebase remote config dependency to library project

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-remote-config

I have a test project [here](https://github.com/fweigl/FirebaseThrowAway) with the modules

- `app`
- `mylibrary`

`mylibrary` obviously is a library project, and the `app` module uses that module. 
I want to add the [Firebase remote config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android) to the library module (adding it to the app module works all fine).

I added to the top-level `build.gradle`:

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

and of course the actual dependency on the library module:

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.4.0'
```

Now I've tried two variations:

**1.** When I apply the google services plugin on the `mylibrary` module with

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the project doesn't compile with the following error:

> Error:(34, 0) Could not get unknown property 'LibraryVariants' for
>   object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension

**2.** When I apply the plugin to the `app` module, the project compiles, but at runtime I get the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.firebasethrowaway-2/base.apk", zip file (...)

and

> Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/safeparcel/AbstractSafeParcelable;
>
> at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx.zzbd(android.content.Context)
>   ((null):-1)

Any idea how I can add the firebase dependency via my library module?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Delblanco Nope.